# 2 Sites - 2 DBs, Master of 1 is Slave of other?

Tags: mysql

We have 2 separate projects (we've inherited one and have one inhouse). They're not overly related to each other but they share a fair bit of data (and that is expanding daily).

We were going to join both schemas in one DB and have a seperate server as a slave for both. However, I was wondering if, to minimize load, etc, if we set up 1 server as master for site1, and slave of site2's db, and server 2 would serve reverse roles.

Does this make any sense or are we being silly?

Answer (score 1):

In my own opinion it is perfectly fine to have the set up you want:

- `server 1`: master of database `a`, slave of database `b`
- `server 2`: master of database `b`, slave of database `a`

**only if:**

- Both servers have similar performances (you will want to avoid having a slave to slow, unable to catch up with a master)
- Both servers are able to handle the load of both databases. For example, if `server 2` goes down, `server 1` will become master of `a` and `b` and all the traffic will go there. You want to make sure it can handle this traffic